# Shell separate line into multiple lines after every number

Tags: bash, shell

So I have a selection of text files all of which are on one line
I need a way to seperate the line into multiple lines after every number.

At the minute I have something like this

```
a 111111b 222c 3d 444444
```

and I need a way to get it to this

```
a 11111
b 222
c 3
d 444444
```

I have been trying to create a gawk with regex but I'm not aware of a way to get this to work. (I am fairly new to shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy with `sed`.

```
$: cat file
a 51661b 99595c 65652d 51515

$: sed -E 's/([a-z] [0-9]+)\n*/\1\n/g' file
a 51661
b 99595
c 65652
d 51515
```

Pretty easy with `awk`.

```
$: awk '{ print gensub("([a-z] [0-9]+)\n*", "\\1\n", "g") }' file
a 51661
b 99595
c 65652
d 51515
```

Could even do with bash built-ins only...but don't...

```
while read -r line
do while [[ "$line" =~ [a-z]\ [0-9]+ ]]
   do printf "%s\n" "$BASH_REMATCH"
      line=${line#$BASH_REMATCH}
   done
done < file
a 51661
b 99595
c 65652
d 51515
```

Comment: Note that this uses the array in a scalar context, which will return the first element. Probably better to be clear and explicit, but for an example I thought the simpler syntax might help someone get the idea.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried with regex before but definitely wasn't going to be able to manage that

Answer (score 0):

You already have a good answer from Paul, but for `sed` an arguably more direct expression simply using the first two numbered backreferences separated by a newline would be:

```bash
sed -E 's/([0-9])([^0-9])/\1\n\2/g' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

In your case that would be:

```
$ echo "a 111111b 222c 3d 444444" | sed -E 's/([0-9])([^0-9])/\1\n\2/g'
a 111111
b 222
c 3
d 444444
```